# File does not exits or found

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

I'm implementing captcha in project. I am using codeigniter framework. In captcha_helper.php file the code

```
$use_font = ($font_path != '' AND file_exists($font_path) AND function_exists('imagettftext')) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

is returning false. Because `file_exists($font_path)` is returning **false**. 
I'm passing

```
$img_path = '../../captcha/';
        $img_url = base_url() . 'captcha/';
        $font_path = base_url(). 'captcha/font/impact.ttf';

$captch = array(
            'word' => '',
            'img_path' => $img_path,
            'img_url' => $img_url,
            'font_path' => $font_path,
            'img_width' => '200',
            'img_height' => '50',
            'expiration' => '300'
        );
 $cap = create_captcha($captch);
```

Now, when I echo `$font_path` and copy and paste the same url in browser, the font file is prompted to be download means path is correct. So, why `file_exists($font_path)` is returning **false**.
I tried my best could not figure it out. Please help me, and forgive my silly mistakes if there are any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$font_path = realpath($image_path . 'font/impact.ttf');
```

The problem is that `base_url()` returns a URL and you need to be looking on the local filesystem using the full path (e.g. `/home/yoursite/public_html/captcha/font/impact.ttf`)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php), file_exists accepts as its argument the filename: a path to the file or directory, not a URL to it. It doesn't access files using an HTTP request. I bet `file_exists('/captcha/font/impact.ttf')` would return true!